# Changing all labels colour after disabling the frame

Tags: vba, excel, tags

I need some help in turning the label colours of a frame to Gray after disabling it. Enabling and disabling the frame is quite easy but I'm straggling on how getting all labels belonging to that frame and changing the colour to Gray. I tried to  tag all the frame text boxes with their respective labels , and working on the text box level but it is just not working. Here is my code:

```
Private Sub cbxCSENetworkDeseign_Click()
Dim Tbox As MSForms.TextBox

    If cbxCSENetworkDeseign.Value = True Then  'Check box that will disable / enable the frame
        frmCustomerDetails.Enabled = False
        For Each Tbox In frmCustomerDetails.Controls
            Controls(Tbox.Tag).ForeColor = vbGrayText
        Next Tbox
    Else
        frmCustomerDetails.Enabled = True
        For Each Tbox In frmCustomerDetails.Controls
            Controls(Tbox.Tag).ForeColor = vbBlack
        Next Tbox
    End If   
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub cbxCSENetworkDeseign_Click()
Dim Tbox As Object   'MSForms.TextBox

    If cbxCSENetworkDeseign.Value = True Then  'Check box that will disable / enable the frame
        frmCustomerDetails.Enabled = False
        For Each Tbox In frmCustomerDetails.Controls
            Tbox.ForeColor = vbGrayText
        Next Tbox
    Else
        frmCustomerDetails.Enabled = True
        For Each Tbox In frmCustomerDetails.Controls
            Tbox.ForeColor = vbBlack
        Next Tbox
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

@Excel Hero
Thankx Bud.
but after re-checking my code , I found that what is missing is to complete all the Tags in my frame ( some of them were empty) , so when I run it it is actually working.
thx bud again
;)